# Transaction Service - Indexing past events/safes/transactions

Tags: gnosis-safe

I've deployed my own transaction service for goerli but the service it's indexing only new safes and transactions.

Is there a way to launch/trigger the reindexing of past safes/transactions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That's weird, as the service should be indexing transactions since the Safe Master copies were deployed. I didn't find any issue when deploying new services.

Take into consideration that service will take some time (maybe days) to index everything. Could you check what the `/api/v1/about/indexing/` endpoint is returning?